# How to allow scrolling the last item of recyclerview above of the FAB?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a FAB on top at the right bottom.

When scrolling I would like to allow the user to scroll further up such that the last item is fully visible and not covered by the FAB. It would be ok to allow an additional 48px at the bottom showing the background.

I tried adding a transparent footer item which does the trick. However, after adding sorting to the list, the transparent footer item creates some UI glitches during sorting (the divider is shown below the normal items).

I tried adding margin, but then the space is wasted all the time. It is ok that the FAB covers the last item when user views the first items at the top. Only when that last item is important than the item must not be covered.

This is the layout xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:clipToPadding="false"
     android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/floating_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Update**
Using item decoration is the correct answer here.

Comment: can u show you code ?

Comment: There is no code. Is there an API to tell the scrolling that it can allow more than until the bottom of the last item?

Comment: How about inflating an empty view of height equal to space you want at bottom for your last recycler view item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better solution should calculate scroll range and hide the fab, if content was scroll down.

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
        if (dy > 0) {
            fab.hide();
            return;
        }
        if (dy < 0) {
            fab.show();
        }
    }
});
```

But if you really want to add margin at bottom you should use [ItemDecoratorion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html).

Comment: ItemDecorator could work. I'll try that. Is there a LastItemDecorator somewhere?

Comment: There is no such a decorator((( But thats article should help https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/a-view-divided-adding-dividers-to-your-recyclerview-with-itemdecoration/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Actually there is the EndOffsetItemDecoration: https://github.com/bignerdranch/simple-item-decoration/blob/master/simpleitemdecoration/src/main/java/com/dgreenhalgh/android/simpleitemdecoration/linear/EndOffsetItemDecoration.java